# Run time error 1044 - range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am getting error on the below line item as "range of object _worksheet failed"

`Set founditem = Sheet6.Range("Engagement Code").Find(Target.Value)`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim founditem As Range
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C19")) Is Nothing Then

   Set founditem = Sheet6.Range("Engagement Code").Find(Target.Value)
   
   If Not founditem Is Nothing Then 'found
    Range("C6" & Target.Row).Value = Sheet6.Range("D" & founditem.Row).Value 'Eng.Partner
    Range("C7" & Target.Row).Value = Sheet6.Range("E" & founditem.Row).Value 'Eng.PM
    End If
```

Comment: That means `Sheet6` has no range named "Engagement Code"

Comment: 1044?  Are you sure that it wasn't 1004?

Comment: Do you really mean `Range("C6" & Target.Row)` or rather: `Range("C" & Target.Row)`